# Discord.js Mute bot with optional time and reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js mute bot and I'm having a few issues with it.

How can I make it so when someone used the command `!mute User` it sets the time as `30min` and the reason as `No reason Specified`.
But if they use `!mute @User <Time>`, it will set the time specified by the user and the reason as `No reason Specified`.
And finally, if they use `!mute @User <Reason>`, it will set the time as `30min` and the reason as written in the command.

```js
const userx = message.mentions.users.first();
if (!userx) {
    message.channel.send("**USAGE: `!mute <User> <Time> <Reason>`");
    return;
}

let time = args.slice(1).join(" ");
if (!time) time = "30min";

let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
if (!reason) reason = "No reason Specified";
```

I'm currently having problems with understanding how the `args.slice` works.

Comment: i fixed the message... the site removed stuff between ><

Comment: `args` is an array, therefor look at [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make both the `time` (second argument) and the `reason` (second or third argument) optional, you will need to check a few things:

1. if there are any arguments

   - if there is none, just send the usage info
2. if the first argument is a member mentioned

   - if member is not the first argument, just send the usage info
3. if there is a second argument

   - if there is none, just use the default `time` and `reason`
4. if the second argument is a string you can parse as
   time

   - if you can, update `time`
   - if you can't, it's a `reason`, so chop the first argument and join the rest
5. if the second argument is `time` and there is a third argument

   - chop the first two arguments, join the rest, and update your `reason`

To check the time, you can use a third-party library like [`ms`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms).

Check out the working code below:

```js
const { Client, MessageMentions } = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms');

const client = new Client();
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'mute') {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();

    // check if args[0] is a member
    const firstArgIsMember =
      args[0] && !!args[0].match(MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN);

    if (!member || !firstArgIsMember)
      return message.channel.send('**USAGE: `!mute <User> <Time> <Reason>`**');

    let reason = 'No reason specified';
    let time = '30min';

    // check if args[1] is time
    let secondArgIsTime = !!args[1] && !!ms(args[1]);
    if (secondArgIsTime) {
      time = ms(ms(args[1]), { long: true });
      if (args[2]) reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');
    } else if (!!args[1]) {
      reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    }

    return message.channel.send(
      `${member} is muted for ${time}. Reason: ${reason}`,
    );
  }
});
```

[image]